# Why do I keep getting incompatible type error in Java for the temperature converter I am trying to make?

Tags: java

I am new to the Java language. The only other language I learned was Python. I'm trying to do my assignment for class but I keep getting this error and I have no idea what it even means.

```
import java.util.*; //for Scanner class
public class TempConverter { //an application which will convert temperature from F to C or C to F
   public static void main (String[] args) { 
      Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Welcome to the Temperature Converter! Enter 0 to convert F--> C and 1 to convert from C--> F.\n" + "Enter Control-Z when done!");
      int F2C;
      F2C = stdin.hasNext(); //tells which conversion user wants to do
      if (F2C == 0) { //converting Fahrenheit to Celsius
         System.out.println("Welcome to the F--> C Converter!");
         double tF = stdin.hasNext(); //gets the temperature to convert
         while (stdin.hasNext()) { //keep converting every number the user inputs
            double tC = ((tF-32.0)*5.0) / 9; //formula for converting to Celsius
            System.out.println(tF + "F =" + tC + "C"); //prints converted temperature
            tF = stdin.hasNext(); //takes NEXT temperature to convert
         }
      }   
      if (F2C == 1) { //converting Celsius to Fahrenheit
         System.out.println("Welcome to the C--> F Converter!");
         double tC = stdin.hasNext(); //gets the temperature to convert in Celsius
         while (stdin.hasNext()) { //keep converting every number that user inputs
            double tF = ((tC*9.0)/5) + 32.0; //formula for converting to Fahrenheit
            System.out.println(tC + "C = " + tF + "F");
            tC = stdin.hasNext(); 
         }
      } 
      System.out.println("Goodbye!");    
   }   
}
```

I keep getting these errors:

```
TempConverter.java:7: error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to int
      F2C = stdin.hasNext(); //tells which conversion user wants to do
                         ^
TempConverter.java:10: error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to double
         double tF = stdin.hasNext(); //gets the temperature to convert
                                  ^
TempConverter.java:14: error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to double
            tF = stdin.hasNext(); //takes NEXT temperature to convert
                              ^
TempConverter.java:19: error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to double
         double tC = stdin.hasNext(); //gets the temperature to convert in Celsius
                                  ^
TempConverter.java:23: error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to double
            tC = stdin.hasNext(); 
                              ^
5 errors
```

Comment: Replace `hasNext()` with `next()`

Comment: When you get errors, read the errors. Do you know what `hasNext()` is returning? What type it is returning? And what type `F2C` is? You should check those, and you will have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message say `stdin.hasNext();` returns a boolean value. You assign it to a int `F2C`. What you whant i guess is `F2C = stdin.next();`

This reads the next value from stdin.`hasNext()` only check if there something to read.

Answer (score 0):

The `hasNext()` method of the `Scanner` class returns a `boolean` telling you *whether* there are more items or not. It **does not** give you the next item. Please refer to the documentation for more information:

[Scanner (Java Platform SE 7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

You should use `next()` to retrieve the item, as a `String`. If you're expecting a specific type, you can use `nextInt()`, etc. Like so, for your first loop:

```
      int F2C;
      F2C = stdin.nextInt(); //tells which conversion user wants to do
      if (F2C == 0) { //converting Fahrenheit to Celsius
         System.out.println("Welcome to the F--> C Converter!");
         double tF = stdin.nextDouble(); //gets the temperature to convert
         while (stdin.hasNext()) { //keep converting every number the user inputs
            double tC = ((tF-32.0)*5.0) / 9; //formula for converting to Celsius
            System.out.println(tF + "F =" + tC + "C"); //prints converted temperature
            tF = stdin.nextDouble(); //takes NEXT temperature to convert
         }
      }
```

Comment: Okay I see it now. I just corrected my code but now it's doing something weird:

Comment: It won't print the 1st completed conversion until I enter the next number I want to convert... could it be the order in which my print statements are?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `stdin.next()`, `stdin.nextDouble`, etc.

You are mixing up those with `stdin.hasNext()` (which returns a boolean) - thus the type errors.

Answer (score 0):

The error log is describing the problem, but I'll try to explain:

You're calling the [`hasNext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext--) method on `stdin`, which is a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). `hasNext()` is a method that returns a `boolean` value (`true` or `false`) depending on whether there is more input that can be read.

You're trying to assign this boolean value to `int` (`F2C`) or `double` (`tF` and `tC`) variables.

You probably meant to use the [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) and [`nextDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble--) methods

Answer (score 0):

You also want to read the next double after checking that there is one and not before.

```
     System.out.println("Welcome to the F--> C Converter!");
     while (stdin.hasNextDouble()) { //keep converting every number the user inputs
        double tF = stdin.nextDouble(); //gets the temperature to convert
        double tC = ((tF-32.0)*5.0) / 9; //formula for converting to Celsius
        System.out.println(tF + "F =" + tC + "C"); //prints converted temperature
     }
```